# TFS 2015 xaml build trouble

Tags: xaml, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have setup at my company a test TFS 2015 server, which I had TFS 2015 do the upgrade to our databases.  I am executing one of our xaml build definitions and getting this error in the build log.

```
Target "BeforeLabel: (TargetId:21)" in file "C:\Program Files     (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" from project "C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (target "Label" depends on it):
Done building target "BeforeLabel" in project "TFSBuild.proj".: (TargetId:21)
Target "CoreLabel: (TargetId:22)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" from project "C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (target "Label" depends on it):
Using "Label" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll".
Task "Label" (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:TeamFoundationServerUrl=http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/33336 (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:Name=Endeavor VS2K15 CI_2.2.1.14 VS2K15 (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:Scope=$/Lightning (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:Version=WNPDTFS2015TEST_140_8 (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:Files=$/ (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:Child=Replace (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:Comments=Label created by Team Build (TaskId:19)
 Task Parameter:Recursive=True (TaskId:19)
 Label TeamFoundationServerUrl="http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection" BuildUri="vstfs:///Build/Build/33336" Name="Endeavor VS2K15 CI_2.2.1.14 VS2K15" Scope="$/Lightning" Recursive=True Comments="Label created by Team Build" Version="WNPDTFS2015TEST_140_8" Child="Replace" Files="$/" (TaskId:19)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5,957,5): error : The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree: [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15  CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5,957,5): error : 'VisualBasicValue<LabelChildOption>': Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelChildOption.Fail". [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5,957,5): error : 'LabelChildOption' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client'. [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5,957,5): error :  [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5,957,5): error : 'VisualBasicValue<RecursionType>': Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType.Full". [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5,957,5): error : 'RecursionType' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client'. [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5,957,5): error :  [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018: The "Label" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018: System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException: The following errors were encountered while processing the workflow tree: [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018: 'VisualBasicValue<LabelChildOption>': Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelChildOption.Fail". [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018: 'LabelChildOption' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client'. [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:  [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018: 'VisualBasicValue<RecursionType>': Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType.Full". [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018: 'RecursionType' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client'. [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:  [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.ValidateWorkflow(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager) [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.RegisterExtensionManager(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager) [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.EnsureInitialized() [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.RunInstance(WorkflowApplication instance) [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout) [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow, IDictionary`2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions) [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.WorkflowTask.ExecuteInternal() [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.Task.Execute() [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets(957,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() [C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj]
Done executing task "Label" -- FAILED. (TaskId:19)
Done building target "CoreLabel" in project "TFSBuild.proj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:22)
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\8\Lightning\Endeavor VS2K15 CI\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (EndToEndIteration target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

Comment: That's too bad.  What did you do to try and fix the build?

Comment: These assemblies are no longer stored in the GAC in TFS 2015, so it may be looking for them in the wrong location.

Comment: According to your log, you are still using TFSBuild.proj file, but in TFS2010 and newer, TFS uses the workflow based Team Build system and it no longer uses the TFSBuild.proj method. Which version of TFS are you trying to upgrade from? If you create a new XAML build definition, are you able to queue a successful build?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Yes I am to queue one of our XAML build definitions.  We were using TFS 2013 and trying to go to TFS 2015.  I was wondering in our UpgradeTemplate.xaml where it has xmlns for the namespaces and assemblies is there a way to specify which version to use specifically?  I am thinking that could be the problem since I looked into my GAC with command line and it has multiple versions of this assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.   Sorry I if some of this seems basic, I got assigned this project and have not done anything with TFS before this.

Comment: I would recommend that you switch from the 'UpgradeTemplate.xaml' to the 'DefaultTemplate.xaml' as the Upgrade one was only created for backward compatibility with 2005/2008 Team Foundation Build, which is too old to support.